# Error: your api key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly (React Native with Firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

Hi i'm really new on these topics. I am currently working on an android emulator with react native using javascript and firebase. I'm getting this error over and over again even though i've checked and replaced my api key and 100% sure that it is correct.

Here's the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import reducers from './reducers';
import LoginForm from './components/loginForm';

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: 'apiKeyHere',
      authDomain: 'DomainHere',
      databaseURL: 'URLHere',
      projectId: 'IDHere',
      storageBucket: 'BucketHere',
      messagingSenderId: 'SenderIdHere',
      appId: 'appIdHere',
      measurementId: 'measurementIdHere',
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
        <View
          style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ddd', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <LoginForm />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^7.14.4",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.9.6",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```